# Android Bluetooth printer British Pound Sign(£) does not work

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, printers

I am trying to print the British pound sign, "£", by using Unicode (\u00a3), but it does not work. I am trying to implement the open source project from [GitHub](https://github.com/hejiawang/PrintDemo). All is working well, but when I try to print the "£" sign, then it does not work [? print]. Can any one help to me solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially be an issue with the printer. If you are using a regular printer, this probably isn't the issue, but specialty printers can have their own special set of characters installed. For some specialty printers, you may need to install a font that includes this character or switch character set you're using. I would recommend checking out the manufacturer's site if this is the case, or look to see if they have a developer forum.